Why does deleting files on FAT32 USB flash drive on macOS just rename the files and doesn't delete them?
I commonly have to prepare files on a FAT32-format USB flash drive, using a Mac, and then put the stick into a TV for its native slide show display.
Using Finder, I'll move the old contents to trash, and then copy over the new contents. I then eject the USB flash drive, and wait for it to quiesce before removing it (it has an activity LED which stops flashing).
However, when the stick is inserted into the TV (or a PC), the files are still there, renamed with a ._ (I think) prefix. Even though nothing is shown in the folder by Finder.
How can I really and truly get the macOS Finder to delete the files completely from the FAT32 USB flash drive?

Empty the trash first?

Those are not deleted files, those are metadata files (in AppleDouble format) that macOS creates to store properties of the new files that FAT32 doesn't handle natively. See "Disable creation of .AppleDouble files on Mac OS X"

@GordonDavisson Thanks, this makes sense. So there's no other way to truly clean the folder without running a manual step afterwards? I did try emptying the trash at one point but the problem still occurred. It's possible I ejected and reinserted the volume before emptying the trash, however, and maybe that confused Finder.

@BobDoolittle Yes, you need to run a manual step. Emptying the trash is irrelevant to the "._" files (although you might also need to delete the ".Trashes" folder, which can get left around even after you delete all the files that were in it).

You can remove ._ files on your FAT32 USB flash drive by entering the command below in a Terminal application window.
dot_clean /Volumes/<Name of Volume>

Here you would replace <Name of Volume> with the "Name & Extension" shown in the "Get Info" window for the volume.
To do this from the Finder you would have use the Automator application to create a quick action. Below are two fast ways to acquire this quick action. Details for each are given below.

Create a simple one yourself. The instructions given in this answer will not specify any dot_clean options and logs all output, which can be viewed by the Console application.
Download a third party quick action. The one given in this answer is written in AppleScript, which allows the user to select the options for the dot_clean command and displays dialogs and notifications when appropriate. All output is logged, which can be viewed by the Console application.

Create One Yourself
The steps are given below.

Open Automator application and select a new quick action. Older versions of macOS refer to this as a service.

Drag "Run a Shell Script" to your empty workflow.

Replace any existing script with the following
{
  echo -n "dot_clean"
  printf " %q" "$@"
  echo
  dot_clean "$@"
  status=$?
  echo "Returned status: $status"
  exit $status
} >> ~/Library/Logs/Finder.log 2>&1

Basically, this script prints the dot_clean command to be executed, then executes the command. All output is sent to the Finder.log, which can be viewed by the Console application.

Save using the name "Dot Clean". The workflow file ~/Library/Services/Dot Clean.workflow will be created.

Configure the rest of the workflow as shown below. This was created using macOS Sonoma 14.7.1.


Close the workflow. Quit the Automator application.


Below is an example, where all the ._ files are being removed from a flash drive.

The following output was appended to the ~/Library/Logs/Finder.log file.
dot_clean /Volumes/MYFLASHDRV
Failed trying to change dir to .Spotlight-V100
Bad Pathname: Operation not permitted
Failed trying to change dir to .TemporaryItems
Bad Pathname: Operation not permitted
Returned status: 0

This output can be viewed in the Console application, as shown below.

Download from the Internet
I wrote a workflow which uses AppleScript instead of a Bash script. This can be found at the SourceForge Dot Clean Project. The installation and usage instructions can be found here. Using the same flash drive as before produces the following popup, where dot_clean options can be selected. Here, "Continue" was chosen without selecting any options.

The following notification was issued.

The following output was appended to the ~/Library/Logs/Finder.log file.
**********
2024-12-04 20:13:34 Dot Clean executing: dot_clean '/Volumes/MYFLASHDRV' 2>&1
2024-12-04 20:13:34 Dot Clean completed with a status of 0:
Failed trying to change dir to .Spotlight-V100
Bad Pathname: Operation not permitted
Failed trying to change dir to .TemporaryItems
Bad Pathname: Operation not permitted

This output can be viewed in the Console application, as shown below.

